# Is there a function $t$ fulfilling $\mathcal{O}(0) \subset \mathcal{O}(t) \subset \mathcal{O}(1)$?

Tags: big-o-notation

$f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is in $\mathcal{O}(0)$ only if $f(n) \neq 0$ for a finite number of values of $n$. Therefore, $\mathcal{O}(0) \subset \mathcal{O}(1)$ strictly. Is there something in between, i.e. a function $t:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $\mathcal{O}(0) \subset \mathcal{O}(t) \subset \mathcal{O}(1)$?

Comment: We very often restrict ourselves to monotonically non-decreasing functions as they make more sense. Consider for example the characteristic function for even numbers, i.e. $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is even and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example: $f(n)=\cases {0&$n\in\mathbb{N}_{even}$\\1&$n\in\mathbb{N}_{odd}$}$

This function is not in $O(0)$, since it has infinitely many $1$'s, but also $1$ is not $O(f)$ since it has infinitely many $0$'s.

To see more clearly why $1$ is not $O(f)$, consider any constant $c>0$ and any constant $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$. Then, **if** $1 \le c\cdot f(n)$ for any $n>n_0$, we will have that for any $n_0<n\in \mathbb{N}_{even}$, $1 \le c\cdot f(n) = c\cdot 0 = 0$ which is a contradiction. Hecne $1\notin O(f)$.

Therefore $O(0)\subsetneq O(f)\subsetneq O(1)$.

However, for computer science usages, as Pal GD said, we consider only monotonically increasing functions - in which case there is no such $f$.

Comment: BTW, if you are considering the case for *little*-o notation, you can prove there is no such function.